# Octobercms how to style paginator

Tags: customization, octobercms, paginator

I am trying to figure out octobercms. Im a beginner. Building a website. And I cannot find any information in the documentation on how to style the paginator.

I already did this:

`````
    {% for user in users %}
        {{ user.name }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{{ users.render|raw }} // This renders pagination links````

And that's great! But how to give the rendered html some different classes for example? 
Or should add custom css to the markup that is rendered or should I make a paginator myself?
So many questions ;)
`````

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, I got an answer, here:

https://octobertricks.com/tricks/customize-pagination-markup

Best
R

Answer (score 0):

October use Laravel Pagination. Is in Store in `vendor/laravel/src/illuminate/pagination`. There are 4 views pagination
[image]

In your template you can call it by using
`{{ posts.links('pagination::bootstrap-4').render()|raw }}`

However in your plugin there is a file Builder and you can override the [View] path by creating new Render function.